# How to find a digit within an integer in PHP; for example to find the position of 23 in 123456

Tags: php

I need to find the digits `23` within another integer, `123456`.

I have written a function that finds the mod of another number, hence eventually finds the desired output:

```
<?php 

$digit = 23;
$anotherNumber = 123456;
while($anotherNumber > 0) {
    $reminder = $anotherNumber % 10;
    if ($reminder == $digit) {
       $pos++;
    }
    $anotherNumber /= 10;

    print $pos;
}

?>
```

I get the output `6 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` whereas I need the position of the integer.

Comment: it should be  `anotherNumber % 100`  instead of  `anotherNumber % 10`

Answer (score 1):

You're not really trying to treat these numbers as numbers; you want to treat them as strings. So, you should do that explicitly.

```
$digit = 23;
$anotherNumber = 123456;
$position = strpos((string) $anotherNumber, (string) $digit);
```

Note the warnings in [the manual entry for `strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (emphasis added):

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). **Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.**
>
> **Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.**

Comment: I would recommend to not use concatenation to cast int to string. Just use the string cast unary operátor `(string) $var`

Comment: @slepic Good point; I honestly don’t know why I did that. Fixed.